# Typoscript CASE & default value

Tags: typo3, typoscript

See below for my typoscript code

```
    typolink.parameter.cObject = CASE
    typolink.parameter.cObject {
        key.field = pid
        3725 = TEXT
        3725.value = 5574

        5515 = TEXT
        5515.value = 5574

        3748 = TEXT
        3748.value = 5574

        default = TEXT
        default.data = pid

    }
```

What I am trying to implement is , In a CASE block, I am trying to generate the typolink url's. So if the pid is 3725 Or 5515 Or 3748 then I will use 5574 as my single view page id. If there is a pid that doesn't comes under the condition then I want to use pid as my single view page id . Tried the below code but that doesn't work for me . Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Try `default.data = field:pid`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `default.data = field:pid` instead of `default.data = pid`. TYPO3 needs to know where to look for `pid`, it could be a request parameter, register, configuration setting and so on as well.